# Bash, Fish: prevent variable expansion

Tags: shell, variables, fish, expansion

Am planing to switch to fish as my default shell but am having some troubles with it.
Before rewrite all my script I would like to reuse the old ones using bash with '-c' option.
Example:

```
bash -c "cat <<'EOF' | tee filename >/dev/null
$SHELL
$TERM
EOF"
```

Even using `'EOF'`, I always get:
`/bin/fish`
`xterm`

If posible, I would like to avoid to use a backslash `\$SHELL` in every variable in the script.

Comment: The variables are replaced by the top level shell before `bash -c ...` is executed.

Comment: Nested shells like that and getting appropriate quoting for both gets real ugly real fast. My rule of thumb is to just avoid that style.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here is that $SHELL does not mean what you think it means.

$SHELL is *not* "the currently running shell", it is "the user's configured login shell".

Neither bash nor fish (nor zsh for that matter) will set it, they'll inherit it from your login stack.

That means either what you are actually trying to do *will not work*, or your test will have misleading results.

The next step is that the argument, to fish, is double-quoted:

```
bash -c "..."
```

That means variables inside those will be expanded *by fish*, before bash runs. You can single-quote them:

```
bash -c '...'
```

This means you'll need to escape any single-quotes in the argument like

```
bash -c 'cat <<\'EOF\' | tee filename >/dev/null                                               
$SHELL
$TERM
EOF'
```

Of course this will tell bash to do

```
cat <<'EOF' | tee filename >/dev/null
$SHELL
$TERM
EOF
```

which means *bash* won't expand the variables either. If that's what you want, to print a literal "$SHELL" and "TERM", that's fine. If not, you can use `EOF` without the quotes to let *bash* expand the variables.

This won't look any different because (see above) $SHELL won't change between the two shells. You can use a variable only set in bash to confirm it's working:

```
bash -c 'cat <<EOF | tee filename >/dev/null                                               
$BASH_VERSION
$TERM
EOF'
```

this will give you your bash's version in "filename".

The issues with nested quoting and escaping and which shell expands which variable are why I would usually recommend just writing a bash script.

Make a file called "printshell" with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF | tee filename >/dev/null
$SHELL
$TERM
EOF
```

make it executable (`chmod +x`) and put it somewhere in your $PATH. If you don't have a suitable directory you can create one (`mkdir`) and add it to fish's $PATH with `fish_add_path`. This allows you to run it as `printshell` without having to use the full path, like it's a function in the shell.

(of course it won't have access to the shell's state, so you won't have all your variables, only the exported ones, or be able to `cd` and have that stick outside. For that you'll have to use fish script)

Comment: Thank you for correctly identifying SHELL as "not the currently running shell".  The proliferation of that particular fallacy is painful to witness.